# VBA Macro for MS Word to Ignore Spelling Errors in Selected Block of Text

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

VBA Noob here.  I take my python programming notes in a word document since I can import images into it and align/format text quickly.  Any code pasted into this document comes up as a spelling error.  I'm trying to find a way to ignore spelling errors within a selected text area so I don't have to deal with ignoring each spelling error line of code individually.  I don't want to turn off spell check in the document.

Ideally, I'd able to write a macro that read:

```
Selection.ShowSpellingErrors = True
```

but ShowSpellingErrors() can only be used with ActiveDocument.  I was able to a record a macro that ignored spelling errors with:

```
Selection.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS 
Selection.NoProofing = True
```

However, any new text I type into this also doesn't get proofed, which is something I don't want.  I want to be able to write new text and see any errors I make.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Since you're selecting the no-proofing sections manually, is there a reason why you want to set the no-proofing by code instead of Word's menu?

Comment: @A.S.H, because I'm not always selecting small no-proofing areas manually.  Sometimes I'm copy and pasting pages of R console output and graphics then continuing to add my own notes. I'm essentially trying to loop through a large amount of text and ignore each spelling error one time.

Answer (score 0):

Not a VBA Macro, but I think this answer may be relevant to your problem anyway.

Try creating a style for code which does not include spell check. Anything with this style does not get spell checked, while the rest of the document does. Sometimes I find the code shows the red underline, but if you run spell check it should just disappear without needing to be 'fixed'.

Create a new style, in the modify formatting dialog, go to Format > Language:

[image: Modify style dialog]

Tick the 'Do not check spelling or grammar' checkbox:

[image: Language dialog]

Highlight your code and use the new style. Any text not in this style will still be spellchecked:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is essentially the same end state as Selection.NoProofing = True.  I'm trying to loop through a large amount of text and ignore each spelling error one time.  I want to be able to add my own text to the selection without turning off spell check for it. Thank you Amy!